# Are both files identical?

Tags: bash, scripts

I am currently trying debug part of a script involving creating an feat.scp file.

This file is usually done as such

```
for n in $(seq $nj); do
  cat $mfccdir/raw_mfcc_$name.$n.scp || exit 1;
done > $data/feats.scp || exit 1
```

But I've manually taken the file `raw_mfcc_$name.$n.scp`
and pasted it into `$data` and renamed it to `feats.scp`.

Is this any different from what the for loop is doing?

Comment: Is there only one such `raw_mfcc_$name.$n.scp` file? What this loop does is go from 1 to nj, and outputing the respective file, and stopping at the first gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets go over the loop. The loop is supposed to go over certain range of numbers given by `$nj` variable, and on each iteration print `raw_mfcc_$name.1.scp` , `raw_mfcc_$name.2.scp` and so on, until the `$nj` number. So all those files get dumped into one `feats.scp`.

Now, if you were to take all those files manually and paste them into `feats.scp` one by one , then sure - that's the same. If you pasted just one file into `feats.scp` that's not the same.

There's also small problem here with `cat $mfccdir/raw_mfcc_$name.$n.scp || exit 1;` part. If the `$nj` number is 5 , and files are numbered 1,2,3,5 (missing 4), the script would exit at 4, and it wouldn't include  5 in the output. It is unclear whether it was intended or not, but I would recommend you edit that to at least have `continue` statement instead of `exit` and still deliver the other content into `feats.scp`

Comment: The file wouldn't be blank. It would still have the contents of files 1 to 5. If there files 1,2,3,5,6,7,..9, with a gap at four, then this loop will only output 1 to 3.

Comment: @muru tested it, you're right.  I used to think the whole content needs to be buffered first before being output to the file